# How to install Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04 on Dell XPS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, dell

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04 on a Dell XPS 15 9560. For that I downloaded the desktop ISO and used `dd` to put it on a USB drive. When booting the laptop I use `F10` to select to boot from USB. Then I get the GRUB selection screen:

- Try Ubuntu without installing
- Install Ubuntu
- OEM install
- Check disc for defects

I choose the first *Try Ubuntu without installing*. Now the purple loading splash appears but the system then freezes on both Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04. Same happens if I select *Install Ubuntu*.

My system settings are:

- Boot List Option: UEFI
- Enable Legacy Option ROMs: off
- Enable Attempt Legacy Boot: off
- Secure Boot: enabled

Now I read that there is a bug apparently with the graphics programs and that it may help to set `nouveau.setmode=0` at boot in Grub. So I guess I press `c` soon as I see the four Grub options and then add the `nouveau` setting somewhere. But none of that worked so far. I believe I need another setting somewhere.

Any idea what to set? Do I have to change something with the `UEFI` settings?

Comment: I have this too trying to install from a USB.  I found booting to windows first then re-starting sometimes allows it to get a little further in installation, as does not turning on the WiFi.  However, I have never managed to get past the Region Select screen.  Laptop locks up hard, no mouse , caps-lock light, or anything.  It's something specific to the Dell, used exactly the same stick yesterday to install a different machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a Dell Inspiron, and some years ago I received these instructions from Dell support people:
[How to Install Ubuntu Linux on your Dell PC](https://www.dell.com/support/article/br/pt/brdhs1/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en)

They are very basic, and for Ubuntu 16.04, but have some useful instructions about UEFI and Legacy ROMs that I suppose still applies to 18.04.